# Remove or Update library dependency from NuGet package Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

A [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RimDev.Stuntman) my program is using, is an older version of a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer) that has a [security vulnerability](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-q7cg-43mg-qp69). I want to update the NuGet package within the NuGet package to a new version but have not discovered a way to do that.

There is no update to the NuGet package with the dependency with the vulnerability but there is an update for the dependency NuGet with the vulnerability.

Screenshot of nuget package in visual studio 2022
[nuget package in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFg8b.png)

I have tried adding '-IgnoreDependencies' to the install command but that installed the NuGet with the insecure NuGet package.

`Install-Package RimDev.Stuntman -Version 3.0.0 -IgnoreDependencies`

Comment: I would install the specific version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer that has the security fix into your project. The RimDev.Stuntman NuGet package specifies a minimum version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer that it depends on and that will be used by NuGet unless something else requires a later version.

Comment: I totally agree with Matt Ward, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer (>= 2.1.2) is defined in RimDev.Stunuman's dependencies. So it will use this version unless install a later version.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions. You can click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
dotnet add package RimDev.Stuntman --version VERSION_YOU_NEED
```

It will add the package or update it if it is already installed.

Comment: I want to update the NuGet package within the NuGet package to a new version but have not discovered a way to do that. There is no update to the NuGet package with the dependency with the vulnerability but there is an update for the dependency NuGet with the vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install a non-vulnerable version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer. I used Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer(6.0.11) because I tested in a .NET6.0 project.

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the nuget package in Solution Explorer in visual studio:
[image]

Hope it can help you to solve the problem.